# How to read a response as number from server when calling a API by using FETCH in Javascript

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

backend server API  send me a number and i have to fetch it in a response in react front end. But i am not able to read it by using response.json() or response.body(). Can anyone help me how to read the response as a number for fetch repsonse.

```
  let url = "API URl"
    var requestOptions = {
      method: 'GET',
      redirect: 'follow'
    };
 fetch(url + new URLSearchParams({selectedReportName: this.state.selectedRepor}), requestOptions)
        .then( response => response.json())
        .then(data =>{ 
           console.log ("Data " + data)} )
```

Comment: you don't need to call .json() function. Just console.log your response and see what you are getting

Answer (score 0):

```
      let url = "API URl"
    var requestOptions = {
      method: 'GET',
      redirect: 'follow'
    };
 fetch(url + new URLSearchParams({selectedReportName: this.state.selectedRepor}), requestOptions)
        .then( response => response.json())
        .then(data =>{ 
           console.log ("Data " + data)} )
        .catch(err => console.log("err:", err));
```

Try the above-mentioned code, It'll give you an exact error if we're not getting 200 response from the server or something is not working.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to attach catcgh statement in code. It is throwing me below eerorSyntaxError: Unexpected token B in JSON at position 0

Comment: can you paste the error here, seems like you're not getting valid json.

Comment: for testing, just console the response without .json() method

Comment: Response is Object ReadableStream and the backend service ( Node Js) is sending data as number.